# React Native- Linking.addEventListener works for universal link, but not for a deep link

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

This is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  Linking.getInitialURL()
    .then(url => {...})
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

  Linking.addEventListener('url', eventHandler);

  return () => {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', eventHandler);
  };

  }, []);
```

Everything works perfectly fine for universal links, however, for a deep link, the `addEventListener` does not work. The app opens up normally but the `eventHandler` is not being called. However, if the app is closed before opening the deep link, it works fine and executes `getInitialURL`.

Comment: Same problem here with react-native 0.70
Have you found a solution ?

Comment: @Lev if I remember correctly, I just decided to use universal links for everything instead, as a work around.